# Zoom Playing video using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, zooming, avplayer, playing

I am paying a m3u8 video url using `AVPlayer`
Is it possible to zoom the video while playing the video.

```
 let url = URL(string: "http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8")
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

Comment: use videogravity feature

Comment: If you want to zoom by user gestures => UIPinchGestureRecognizer
If you want to zoom a UIView => apply scale transformation on your view

Comment: Just put your `AVPlayer` Inside ScrollVIew set `pinchGestureRecognizer.enabled` in UIScrollview , Implement `viewForZoomingInScrollView` Let me know if it is working

Comment: @vineesh TP did you find any working solution?

Comment: @ZainAli:I didn't get solution for this. My requirement was changed, I stopped the implementation.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya is there any solution other than using scrollView???